# How to create two child process executing parallel from a single parent process in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, fork

Hi I'm working gin C++ on Linux platform.
I have a parent process. i need to create two child process from this parent which will be execute in parallel for some time. While Parent process is waiting for both the process to complete and then it finishes its execution.

any suggestion ?

Comment: @all any code example will give me the exact idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `fork()` and `exec` family of functions to start child processes.
parent process can call `waitpid` till child process exists.

exec link: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_execvp.htm

Answer (score 1):

Spawn the new processes with fork();

Then in the parent process you can use waitpid() to wait for both of them to finish.