# Does the following code runs two child process executing in parallel from a single parent process in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, parallel-processing, fork

I have read that fork can be used to run two child process executing in parallel from a single parent process in C++ as is stated in [How to create two child process executing parallel from a single parent process in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561461/); however, there are no examples to create my own experiments. Hence, I have used the following code, but I am not really sure whether the two process are executing in parallel. Additionally, since the tasks are capturing data from two devices, it is needed to run them in different terminals, and the only thing that comes to my mind is the use of the following line:

```
system("xterm -e ./task1");
```

however, once it has executed the following output is 
`sh: 1: term: not found`

I will appreciate your time in any suggestion or guidance that you can provide

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> 
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  cout << "--beginning of program" << endl;
    int counter = 0;
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // child process
        system("./task1");
cout << "child process" << endl;
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        // parent process
                system("./task2");
cout << "parent process" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
cout << "fork() failed!\n" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "--end of the program" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) it has several chapters to answer your question. Notice that [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) is `fork`-ing then `execve`-ing a `/bin/sh -c` process

Answer (score 0):

The question title implies that you think this code creates two child processes and one parent process, for a total of three processes, while the body of your question implies that you think that there is one parent and one child process.  It's not clear to me which one you actually believe.

To be sure: this code will create one extra child process that does run parallel to the parent, for a total of two processes.